# Creating a calendar event with Google Apps Script from html5 time and date inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have an app that uses the html service to basically create a personal work time clock. I can successfully write the start date and time as well as the end date and time along with a note to a spreadsheet. I can also pull the spreadsheet data and display a table of recent shifts to the app.

The trouble is when I try and create a calendar event. Here is what I have so far.

```
<h1>When Did I Work?</h1>

<div>
  <form id='timeClock'>


 <p class='in'>Date In: <input type="date" id="dateIn" name="dateIn"></p>

<p class='in'>Time In: <input id="clockIn" type="time" name="clockIn" value="23:00:00">   </p>


<p class='out'>Date Out: <input type="date" id="dateOut" name="dateOut"></p>

 <p class='out'>Time Out: <input id="clockOut" type="time" name="clockOut" value="07:30:00"></p>


<textarea name="note"></textarea>

<p><input type='submit'value="Submit"></p>

</form>

<h3 class='hide'>Submitted:</h3>
<p id='dayIn'></p>
<p id='timeIn'></p>
<p id='dayOut'></p>
<p id='timeOut'></p>
<p id='noteSum'></p>

 <? var data = displayData(); ?>
<table>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <tr>
    <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
      <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
     <? } ?>
  </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>

<a href="" target="_blank">Open SpreadSheet</a> 

/div>
<?!=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CSS').getContent(); ?>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



$('#timeClock').submit(function(){

    var dateIn = $('#dateIn').val();
    var timeIn = $('#clockIn').val();
    var dateOut = $('#dateOut').val();
    var timeOut = $('#clockOut').val();
    var note = $('textarea').val();

       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
        $('#timeClock').slideUp();
        $('.hide').show().text("Submitted: ");
        $('#dayIn').text("Date In: " + dateIn);
         $('#timeIn').text("Time In: " + timeIn);
         $('#dayOut').text("Date Out: " + dateOut);
         $('#timeOut').text("Time Out: " + timeOut);
         $('#noteSum').text("Note: " + note);

           console.log(ret);
        }).sendClock(this);

       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
         console.log(ret);
         }).logHours(this);

  });

});
</script>



 Code.gs
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
             .evaluate().setTitle('whendidiwork')
             .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return html;
}

function sendClock(form){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('').getSheets()[0];
  ss.insertRowAfter(1);
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, 1, 5);
  var values = [[ form.dateIn, form.clockIn, form.dateOut, form.clockOut, form.note]];
  range.setValues(values);
  Logger.log(values);

  return values;
}

function displayData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('').getSheets()[0];
  var data = ss.getSheetValues(1, 1, 7, 5);
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;

}

function logHours(form){
  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('work hours', new Date(form.dateIn + form.clockIn),
                                                           new Date(form.dateOut + form.clockOut),{description: form.note});
 Logger.log(event);
  return event;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*[user answered his own question, but edited the question instead of answering. I'm trying to salvage it here by copying his edit into a community wiki answer]*

I finally figured out how to get this to work. Here is what I changed. Within the submit function I formatted the input values like this.

```
var start = new Date(dateIn+ " " +timeIn).toString();
var end = new Date(dateOut+ " " +timeOut).toString();
```

This is the server call.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
  console.log(ret);
}).logHours(start, end, note);
```

Here is the code.gs function

```
function logHours(start, end, note){
   var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("").createEvent('TFO: ' + note, new Date(start), new Date(end), {description: note});
   return event;
 }
```

The rest of the code.

```
<form id='timeClock'>
  <p class='in'>Date In: <input type="date" id="dateIn" name="dateIn"></p>
  <p class='in'>Time In: <input id="clockIn" type="time" name="clockIn" value="23:00:00">   </p>
  <p class='out'>Date Out: <input type="date" id="dateOut" name="dateOut"></p>
  <p class='out'>Time Out: <input id="clockOut" type="time" name="clockOut" value="07:30:00"></p>
  <textarea name="note"></textarea>
  <p><input type='submit'value="Submit"></p>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#timeClock').submit(function(){
      var dateIn = $('#dateIn').val();
      var timeIn = $('#clockIn').val();
      var dateOut = $('#dateOut').val();
      var timeOut = $('#clockOut').val();
      var note = $('textarea').val();

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
        $('#timeClock').slideUp();
        $('.hide').show().text("Submitted: ");
        $('#dayIn').text("Date In: " + dateIn);
        $('#timeIn').text("Time In: " + timeIn);
        $('#dayOut').text("Date Out: " + dateOut);
        $('#timeOut').text("Time Out: " + timeOut);
        $('#noteSum').text("Note: " + note);

        console.log(ret);
      }).sendClock(this);

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
        console.log(ret);
      }).logHours(this);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
             .evaluate().setTitle('whendidiwork')
             .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return html;
} 


function logHours(form){
  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('work hours', new Date(form.dateIn + form.clockIn),
                                                           new Date(form.dateOut + form.clockOut),{description: form.note});
  Logger.log(event);
  return event;
}
```